# Frontend public message with close or hide button

Tags: ee2, conditionals, messages

I'm looking for a way to display entries from a channel as a message on the homepage that are able to be hidden once the visitor has read it.  Anyone know of a simple way to  achieve this or an add-on that would help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This really is a questions about HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

From the EE side, in the past I've used a global variable to allow the admins to set a message to be displayed.

Then in the template you just have a conditional surrounding the appropriate markup.

```
{if gv_important_message != ""}
<div class="message">
    <p>{gv_important_message}</p>
</div>
{/if}
```

Obviously the markup would be dependent on the design of the site and your CSS, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Indeed, this is a front-end question, not a backend/EE question. Modals / pop-up box libraries abound, google should get you pointed in the right direction.